# How To Include External Microphone Audio In Headphones?

Tags: audio, usb, headphones, microphone

I have a pair of headphones with an AntLion ModMic (https://antlionaudio.com) that I use for making VoIP calls with a soft phone. Everything is working properly with one small caveat -- *I can't hear audio from the microphone in my headphones.*

Audio input is coming from the AntLion through a Plantronics USB adapter. Audio output is coming from a USB DAC to my Sony headphones. So separate inputs and outputs.

When I use a single USB headset, the microphone audio is blended in with what I hear in the headphones and I'd like to do the same thing with the two separate sources.

The only solution I have found is to use SoundSource (http://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) and use the audio play through feature. Not the end of the world, but I was wondering if anyone had any other suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to end up sounding like a one-man advertising campaign for Rogue Amoeba ;-)
<sub>No affiliation, merely a satisfied user, for many years</sub>

Unless you want to mess with the highly unreliable [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) - originally made by Cycling 74, once maintained by Rogue Amoeba but now open-sourced at [GitHub](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases) - then the only way to go is something made & still supported by Rogue Amoeba.

Audio Hijack, LoopBack & SoundSource are all based on the same [reliable] technology, but tweaked for different sets of user requirements.
SoundSource is the latest - & cheapest - of their offerings.

If it does all that you need, then it's the one to go for.

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin for the feedback. I came to the same conclusion as well based on my research. I had already purchased SoundSource before I posted my question but thought I might be missing something, like a setting, and was overthinking it.

Comment: Is there any documentation for the `Soundflower` configuration? I couldn't find any since it does not have any gui.

Comment: All there is, is on github. I haven't used it since it first got unreliable, about a decade ago.